# LINQ custom sort using comparer

Tags: c#, .net, linq, icomparer

I have a class:

```
public class Item
{
  public int ownerID;
  public decimal value;
}
```

And an array of objects

```
Item[] items;
```

That looks like:

```
ownerID     value
476478      0.65
636566      0.2
```

And I have a second class

```
public class Owner
{
  public int ownerID;
  public int index;
}
```

And an array of objects

```
Owner[] owners;
```

The "owners" is sorted in specific order according the index and looks like:

```
ownerID    index
636566     1
476478     2
```

How can I sort the "items" in the same order as the "owners" using LINQ and comparer?

Would expect something like:

```
items = items.OrderBy(o => o.OwnerID, comparer(o))
```

where comparing made by "index".

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anything you tried so far?

Comment: @Reniuz please see an update. thank you.

Comment: Sorry I can't see your posted code what you have tried.

Comment: If anything, `items.OrderBy(i => i.OwnerID...)` even single letter names should be chosen wisely.

Comment: Can you change the `Item` class to hold a reference to `Owner` instead of just it's id?

Comment: @Reniuz items = items.OrderBy(o => o.OwnerID, comparer(o))

Comment: @ZoharPeled in this array I have just ids

Comment: Can there be items that have no owners, or owners that have no items?

Comment: That is not what you tried. This is what you want. I mean TRIED, wrote a comparer or anything what should lead to expected result. Your question is vague. Please add an example how data looks like and what is expected result. Now this comparer should compare index to what? Can't you just join 2 tables and sort by multiple fields?

Comment: @Reniuz made an additional update

Comment: @ZoharPeled no they match each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming what you're trying to do is to order the items using the index property from the Owner object, something like this should do the job:

```
var joined = items.Join(owners, item => i.OwnerId, owner => o.OwnerId, (item, owner) => new
{
    Item = item,
    Index = owner.Index
});

var orderedItems = joined.OrderBy(j => j.Index).Select(j => j.Item);
```

Comment: Excelent! Thanks.

Comment: But I have another problem - the ordering of "items" should be not according the "index" of "owners" but according actual location of ownerID in the array. How can I change your code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok found the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//Initiate new object 
    Item items= new Items(); 
//Sort the items based on owner ID 
List myList = items.OrderBy(x => x.ownerID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your `Owner` array into a `Dictionary<int, int>` like this:

```
Dictionary<int, int> ownerDict = owners.ToDictionary(x => x.ownerID, y => y.index);
```

And then use that to order the items like:

```
Item[] orderedItems = items.OrderBy(i => ownerDict[i.ownerID]).ToArray();
```

To order the items by the same index, the owners are ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ `.Select()`, it will use a collection iterator to process the collection in its natural order. The lambda inside the Select can then be used to fetch each corresponding item from `items`. Like this:

```
var itemsInOrder = owners
    .Select(x => items.First(item => item.ownerId == x.ownerId))
    .ToArray();
```

This assumes that every ownerId can be found in `items`. If that is not true then you will have to extend it a little, e.g. like this:

```
var itemsInOrder = owners
    .Select(x => items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.ownerId == x.ownerId))
    .Where(item => item != null)
    .ToArray();
```